# UnicodeEncodeError writing text with special character to file

Tags: python, encoding, io

I get a `UnicodeEncodeError` writing text with a special character to a file:

```
  File "D:\SOFT\Python3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 956: character maps to <undefined>
```

My code:

```
expFile = open(expFilePath, 'w')
# data var is what contains a special char
expFile.write("\n\n" + data)
```

The data is probably some weird character from something like Microsoft Word that got pasted into the application's HTML form and it got persisted, now I am importing it. I can't even see it, shows as a diamond in my DB editor when I query it. It just has a placeholder in the text editor. The input should be more rigorously checked for character set compliance but it is not.

Is there a way to encode the data to make any character digestable for I/O processing?

Alternatively, is there a way to check whether my str is compliant to the character standard expected by file IO in order to do replacements of any data that violates it?

Comment: This is beside the point, but what exactly does `data` contain?

Comment: If you really want to write arbitrary bytes, try `b` as a modifier for `open` to switch to binary mode.

Comment: it's probably some weird character from something like Microsoft Word that got pasted into the application's HTML form and it got processed, now I am importing it. I can't even see it, shows as a diamond in my DB editor when I query it. It just has a placeholder in the text editor.  The input should be more rigorously checked for character set compliance but it is not

Comment: my gut feeling is that it is probably either an en or em dash...

Comment: You are relying on the *default encoding*. Don't. Explicitly state an encoding with `encoding=...` when opening the file.

Comment: you mean when doing `expFile = open(expFilePath, 'w')` ?

Comment: That should be `expFile = open(expFilePath, 'w', encoding='UTF-8')`. Please check the [documentation for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: WORKED !! if you put that as an answer, i will upvote and accept

Comment: Give the upvote to ShadowRanger. He wrote a nice explanation and I'm not a point hunter anyway. ;-)

Comment: Your gut feeling about \ufffd is way off track. Please ask another question to get some clues about it including what to do when you find it in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that opening in text mode on your Windows system defaulted to the locale code page, `cp1252`, an ASCII superset that only encodes a tiny fraction of the Unicode range.

To fix, supply a more comprehensive encoding that can support the whole Unicode range; `open` accepts a keyword argument to override the default encoding, so it's as simple as changing:

```
expFile = open(expFilePath, 'w')
```

to

```
expFile = open(expFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Depending on your needs, I'd choose either `utf-8` or `utf-16`; the former is more compact for mostly ASCII text, and is commonly seen everywhere, while the latter matches Microsoft's typical encoding for storing portable (non-locale dependent) text, so it's possible a few Windows-specific text editors would recognize it/handle it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to determine the correct encoding of your file. You can use the chardet library to automatically detect the encoding.

import chardet

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as file:
result = chardet.detect(file.read())

encoding = result['encoding']

with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding=encoding) as file:
data = file.read()