# Which character encoding Python 3.x supports for file I/O?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I [had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000507/unicodeencodeerror-writing-text-with-special-character-to-file) writing a `UTF-8` supported character (`\ufffd`) to a text file. I was wondering what the most inclusive character set `Python 3.x` supports for writing string data to files.

I was able to overcome the problem by

> valEncoded = (origVal.encode(encoding='ASCII', errors='replace')).decode()

which basically filtered out non-ASCII characters from `origVal`. But I figure Python file I/O should support more than ASCII, which is pretty conservative. So I am looking for what is the most inclusive character set supported.

Comment: Any of the UTF-* encodings, including UTF-8.

Comment: if you go to the link, you will see that I was unable to print a UTF-8 character to a text file

Comment: Your character is *Unicode*, not UTF-8. UTF-8 is a codec to encode all of the Unicode standard with. You didn't open your file with UTF-8, you used the default locale (which on Windows is an 8-bit codepage).

Comment: Odds are, you just need to change your `open` call to pass `encoding='utf-8'` as an extra argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the UTF encodings should work:

- UTF-8 is typically the most compact (particularly if the text is largely ASCII compatible), and portable between systems with different endianness without requiring a BOM (byte order mark). It's the most common encoding used on non-Windows systems that support the full Unicode range (and the most common encoding used for serving data over a network, e.g. HTML, XML, JSON)
- UTF-16 is commonly used by Windows (the system "wide character" APIs use it as the native encoding)
- UTF-32 is uncommon, and wastes a lot of disk space, with the only real benefit being a fixed ratio between characters and bytes (you can divide file size by four after subtracting the BOM and you get the number of characters)

In general, I'd recommend going with UTF-8 unless you *know* it will be consumed by another tool that expects UTF-16 or the like.

Comment: For what it's worth: GB18030 is a UFT

Comment: @JohnMachin: I did not know it the expansion from GB2312 had made it comprehensive for the whole Unicode range. Learn something new every day. It seems like it has some flaws relative to the others (not self-synchronizing like UTF-8 for instance), but I suppose it's a viable option if it fits your needs.